# trigger('change') selects the 1st option, which I don't want

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a select that has several options. No empty option.

**Before** calling the trigger none of the options are selected, **after** it runs the first option is preselected, and I want that the select to stay as it was, no option selected

```
$("#selProduct").trigger('change');
```

How to fix this?
I still want to trigger the change, to run the events, but I do not want the first option selected.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you really expect here. When your "change" handler runs, does it check the state of the control? Is something showing in the select pulldown?  If there's something showing, then it's selected.  The default selected option is always the first one unless you set it up differently.

Comment: I want the select to be in unset state. So none of the options are selected, not even the first one. I need selectedIndex = -1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're seeing is the result of the DOM once it's touched and will depend on the browser (but `selectedIndex` *should* be `0` already).

That being, said, use [`.triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) to run *just* the handler, like this:

```
$("#selProduct").triggerHandler('change');
```

For your question though, you may want to store something on the `<select>` on page-load, that changes when it's "touched", for example:

```
$("#selProduct").change(function() { 
  $.data(this, 'changed', false);
  //do stuff
}).data('changed', false);
```

Comment: I used `if ($("#selProduct").val>0) {
 $("#selProduct").trigger('change');
 }`